# HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) run a published program

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have created a program and publish it. It's working fine on my pc. But when I try to run it in a particular PC it gives this error. I use VB.net and access. Use system dsn to connect to the database. I have installed visual studio on that machine and if i open the project and run, it working fine. Which means the machine got all the prerequisites required to run the program. Any Idea what will be the problem.I am adding the contents of the error log file for your reference.

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///F:/Inventory%20Master/Application%20Files/WindowsApplication2_1_0_0_5/WindowsApplication2.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of F:\Inventory Master\Application Files\WindowsApplication2_1_0_0_5\WindowsApplication2.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [27/03/2017 8:10:44 PM] : Activation of F:\Inventory Master\Application Files\WindowsApplication2_1_0_0_5\WindowsApplication2.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [27/03/2017 8:10:44 PM] System.UnauthorizedAccessException
        - Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Comment: `E_ACCESSDENIED` usually indicates a permissions error of some sort.

Comment: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException - Access is denied.` also indicates a permissions error. You could try running the program as administrator if not already. OR, if possible, try running the program through a .NET debugger on the computer the error occurs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. There is some problem or restrictions in that particular account although it's an administrator privilege. I have create a new user account with administrative rights and program runs without error.